# Why mate-panel has a disk Read and disk Write of 2.6GB?

Tags: linux-mint, disk-usage, mate-panel

- Linux Mint 21.2 MATE
- Luks ZFS

The System Monitor shows me a Disk **Read** of 2.6GB Data of mate-panel.

[image]

But in the Properties i read about Disk **Write**:

[image]

1. So why that much Data in that short Time of being active?
2. And why is Read and Write Information swapped?

I installed some Repos and Apps as well but rebooting the System several times.

Comment: swapped: probably because one of the two displays has a bug, or because they mean to be interpreted the other way (which I doubt). It seems realistic that this is some polling thing, i.e. the process just tries to figure out whether something changed. This might even be a temporary file used as backing for some shared memory that never actually leads to disk writes or reads – not quite sure what's meant with "Disk {read|write} total" in this context. maybe it's the cgroup (would seem realistic), but then I'm not sure which controller that would be.